# Fastest Way to Flash OS Image to Raspberry pi SD card

Tags: pi-4, pi-3b+, sd-card, software-installation, raspberry-pi-os

I want to Flash OS Image in a Much Faster way , In network Boot Mode, Currently i am using DD Command to Flash OS to 32 GB SDCARD on Client raspberry pi 4 board, its taking **10mins** for **6.5GB image size**, i want to Flash OS Image using commands like TOOL **"DD"** or any other in fast rate

can i use rpi-clone or pi-clone or SDcard clone kind of tools to quickly flash OS image on raspberry pi SDCARD ?

Comment: Have you timed Pi Imager and Belena Etcher? I suspect they will all be similar due to read/write speed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because what you're doing - or trying to do - is not clear.

Comment: I am trying to Flash OS to the Raspberry Pi 3 and Pi4 board with New OS using Network Boot Method, Now i AM able to do It  with Command prompt and also by Android App used in the remote pi device , as flashing is done with Android Wireless interface its taking more time to flash its taking around 15mins to update OS on remote pi and android app, as DD takes more time, so i am trying to reduce the OS update DD command time , i am trying to update OS just by click of a button in android APP and Jsch android SSH api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps I used to flash an OS Image using Android App

1. Convert 32 GB to 6.5 GB using `pi-shrink`.
2. Compressed 6.5 GB to 2.1 GB by tar method.
3. Splatted 2.1 GB to 200 MB (each of 10 parts) with the Linux `split` command.
4. Placed all 10 Parts in cloud DB.
5. Downloaded 10 parts using download by URL method in Android which took 25 mins.
6. All files downloaded to Android `Download` folder.
7. Send all 10 parts using ssh by Android to Raspberry Pi board.
8. Using shell scripts - merged the parts from 10 parts to 2.1 GB compressed image.
9. Using shell scripts uncompressed 2.1 GB to 6.5 GB OS image.
10. Flashed 6.5 GB image to Client RPi in `Network Boot` Mode.

Thats it! I tried many ways but above took 45 mins to flash OS to remote RPi with android APP.